# Fitted Vs Residuals in monthly time series linear model

Tags: r, time-series, tidyr, forecasting

I am trying to plot the classic "Fitted vs Residual" plot from a time series linear model on the fancy time series in the fpp package:

structure(c(1664.81, 2397.53, 2840.71, 3547.29, 3752.96, 3714.74, 
4349.61, 3566.34, 5021.82, 6423.48, 7600.6, 19756.21, 2499.81, 
5198.24, 7225.14, 4806.03, 5900.88, 4951.34, 6179.12, 4752.15, 
5496.43, 5835.1, 12600.08, 28541.72, 4717.02, 5702.63, 9957.58, 
5304.78, 6492.43, 6630.8, 7349.62, 8176.62, 8573.17, 9690.5, 
15151.84, 34061.01, 5921.1, 5814.58, 12421.25, 6369.77, 7609.12, 
7224.75, 8121.22, 7979.25, 8093.06, 8476.7, 17914.66, 30114.41, 
4826.64, 6470.23, 9638.77, 8821.17, 8722.37, 10209.48, 11276.55, 
12552.22, 11637.39, 13606.89, 21822.11, 45060.69, 7615.03, 9849.69, 
14558.4, 11587.33, 9332.56, 13082.09, 16732.78, 19888.61, 23933.38, 
25391.35, 36024.8, 80721.71, 10243.24, 11266.88, 21826.84, 17357.33, 
15997.79, 18601.53, 26155.15, 28586.52, 30505.41, 30821.33, 46634.38, 
104660.67), .Tsp = c(1987, 1993.91666666667, 12), class = "ts")

```
library(fpp)
fit = tslm(fancy ~ trend + season)
plot(fitted(fit), residuals(fit), xlab = "Predicted scores", ylab = "Residuals")
```

The plot is messy because fitted(fit) and residuals(fit) are again monthly time series object and hence the scatterplot does not work.

How can I display the scatterplot as usual in a normal lm?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody,

I found a quick turnaround for this, by transforming ts into vectors before plotting:

```
fit_vector <- as.vector(fitted(fit))
fit_residuals <- as.vector(residuals(fit))
plot(fit_vector, fit_residuals, xlab = "Predicted scores", ylab = "Residuals")
```